# (Maps) Avoid camera to comeback to prior position when I add a new Pin

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, geolocation

I have an app that shows a Map and a Pin on the center of it(just like Uber and PedidosYa), I have a button that when I click it sends the location where the pin's on. And it makes to appear the closest stores around that pin.

My problem is that when the first time the map appears its centered in my location, I move the map around to locate the pin, and when I click the button I want the map to stay there, but its comeback to the prior location and THEN moves the camera to the location where I drop the pin. I want to avoid that moving.

The function I use when I click the button to drop the pin is something like this:

```
var CenterPos = customMap.GetMapCenterLocation();

            var pinPersonal = new CustomPin()
            {
                Id = "000",
                Position = new Position(CenterPos.Latitude, CenterPos.Longitude),
                Label = "Mio",
                Url = "Mío"
            };

            customMap.Pins.Add(pinPersonal);
```

This draws a pin where I click the button. If I keep it this way, it draws the pin, and the camera comesback to the prior location.

After I use something like this:

```
customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                                    new Position(latitud, longitud), Distance.FromMiles(0.2)));
```

that makes the camera to move to the location I choose. But it comebacks always to the prior location and the moves to the new one.

Any idea? Im not sure from where this behavior comes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement `CustomMap` according with [Customizing a Map Pin - Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin)?

Probably you should override `OnMarkerClickListener.OnMarkerClick` and return `true` in your custom renderer.
This means disable default behavior(centering map, open info-window) and you can implement your own behavior when pin clicked.

See this link.

- [Markers  |  Maps SDK for Android  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#associate_data_with_a_marker)

```
    /** Called when the user clicks a marker. */
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

        // Retrieve the data from the marker.
        Integer clickCount = (Integer) marker.getTag();

        // Check if a click count was set, then display the click count.
        if (clickCount != null) {
            clickCount = clickCount + 1;
            marker.setTag(clickCount);
            Toast.makeText(this,
                           marker.getTitle() +
                           " has been clicked " + clickCount + " times.",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Return false to indicate that we have not consumed the event and that we wish
        // for the default behavior to occur (which is for the camera to move such that the
        // marker is centered and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one).
        return false;
    }
```